# Windows 10 does not wake up from LAN

Tags: networking, windows-10, lan, sleep, wake-on-lan

I have an ASUS EB1012P that had Windows 7 fresh install upgraded to Windows 10 Home.

I am trying to make that machine a family file share drive. But it does not wake from LAN.

I turned on all of Wake on LAN options from within the BIOS. (although I think updating it, may fix it).

I installed the latest Realtek GBE family controller driver (Version 10.009)  ( http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=13&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false ) Version 10.009

And I have all my settings in the hardware set to wake on LAN ready.

But yet I still can't wake up the system from another machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of things that could be wrong here, but let's start on the likely culprits

1) Enable Wake-up-on-lan in Windows.

See here: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-windows-10/

2) Use the driver from ASUS. The generic driver may not have support for wake-on-lan. It is rated for Windows 7 but it should work fine still.

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/DigitalHome/DAV/EB1012P/Realtek_Ethernet_Driver_V7_017_0304_2010.zip

Let me know if that changes anything and we'll do deeper.